# How to add a skip or loop to robo copy

Tags: robocopy

I have a robo copy script that connects to a PC and moves the file to a certain folder. This script does this for 188 PC's, the problem I am having is that if the PC is turned off the script gets stuck on retrying for that PC. How do i add a skip so that the process can move to the next copy.

I am unfamiliar with robo copy so i am not sure.

sample script.

```
robocopy \\PC123\c$\Glory\Archive \\ad.corp.com\files\corp\public\glory\tpblm2/mir /log+:robocopy.log /xf robocopy.log /np /tee
```

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: I was able to use a /R:2 /W:2  in the middle of the script.